# Select Value From Combobox And Add to Sql Database using VB in VS 2010

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I am new to VB and VS 2010. I have a problem.I have created a database.
Now I have created a windows form in which i have added some combo boxes.
I want to select the value of the combo box and when ADD is clicked on the form it should be added to the database.
In textbox we do Textbox1.text to select the value.
What will we do in Combobox .????

Please help me soon...

Thank You in Advance...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get the value of selected item inside the `comboBox` by using the `.Text` property

Comment: You can upvote the correct answer, plus you can select it as an Answer..

Answer (score 0):

[`ComboBox1.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx) will do the same work for Comboboxes, it is same like Textbox1.Text. It will gets or sets the text associated with this control.